# Issue deep linking to MS Excel from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I am trying to open an Excel document that is located on a server. I wrote the following code but it always returns false for    `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL)`

I think I am missing some requirement for deep linking to Excel. Why is iOS not able to understand `ms-excel:ofe|u|` format?

```
@objc static func openExcel() {

    let originalString = "http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=23290165129849240725&t=2329016512984924072514118"
    let encodedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    let encodedURLString = "ms-excel:ofe|u|" + encodedString! + "|n|TestDoc.xlsx|a|App"

    if let url = NSURL(string: encodedURLString), 
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    } else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-excel/id586683407?mt=8&uo=4"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(itunesUrl as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(itunesUrl as URL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but are you sure that you can directly open that excel file in the url you pasted above? When I try to open that `tinyupload` url above I get redirected to `http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=23290165129849240725` where then I can click on a button and perform a proper file download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have analyzed your code and found some mistakes. First, your URL was redirecting to somewhere, as per Microsoft documentation it can't handle redirecting URL's

> The URL has to be encoded and must be a direct link to the file (not a
>   redirect). If the URL is in a format that Office cannot handle, or the
>   download simply fails, Office will not return the user to the invoking
>   application.

Here is [Microsoft Documentation Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx#Invoke%20Office)

The second mistake was you are only encoding the URL string containing site URL, you should consider the part after the scheme `ms-excel:` as a URL and should be encoded.

Because of improper encoding the `let url = URL(string: encodedURLString)` results `nil` that's why it is not working as expected.

Here is an example working code:

```
 @objc static func openExcel() {
        //replace the below url with yours. may be this one dosen't work
        let originalString = "ofe|u|https://pgcconline.blackboard.com/webapps/dur-browserCheck-bb_bb60/samples/sample.xlsx" 
        let encodedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let encodedURLString = "ms-excel:" + encodedString!

        if let url = URL(string: encodedURLString),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        } else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-excel/id586683407?mt=8&uo=4"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(itunesUrl as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(itunesUrl as URL)
        }
    }
```

**Note:** From iOS 9 you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in `Info.plist` under the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key (an array of strings):

For example in our case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When i try to open the [URL in the question above](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=23290165129849240725&t=2329016512984924072514118) I get redirected to [this URL](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=23290165129849240725), so my guess would be that your code is fine, it just might be that your excel file you're trying to open is really an HTML page since `tinyupload` apparently blocks direct links to the files.

Maybe try opening a direct excel file download link, `https://pgcconline.blackboard.com/webapps/dur-browserCheck-bb_bb60/samples/sample.xlsx`  (it was the first google result for '`xlsx file sample download`')